# how to retrieve following error when i execute shell script

Tags: bash, unix, shell-script

I have one script to log into remote server.But i tried to Execute the script some error occur.

Logs:

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
S1=$(ssh -t selvam-odc-shell1 "users | wc -w ")
S2=$(ssh -t selvam-odc-shell2 "users | wc -w ")
S3=$(ssh -t selvam-odc-shell3 "users | wc -w ")
if [ "$S1" -le 100 ];
then 
ssh -t  selvam-odc-shell1 " bash"
if [ "$S2" -le 100 ];
then 
ssh -t  selvam-odc-shell2 "bash"
elif [ "$S3" -le 100 ]; 
then
ssh -t  selvam-odc-shell3 "bash"
else
echo " Shell has been more than 100 users.Please try again later
fi
```

But o/p

```
[user@selvam-odc-sunray2: ~]#./shell.sh
Connection to selvam-odc-shell1 closed.
Connection to selvam-odc-shell2 closed.
Connection to selvam-odc-shell3 closed.
: integer expression expected60
: integer expression expected 29
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks
MM SELVAM

Comment: Are you trying to open 3 shells with your script?

Comment: Yes.Finally i need to login in one shell

Answer (score 0):

The ssh command does not only add the number, it also adds a newline. 
Which means your variables have a content like this: "1\n" which is not an integer.

Remove the quotes: 
S1=$(ssh -t selvam-odc-shell1 users | wc -w )

Comment: Can you provide correct script for above